# Solaris sulog when using sudo

Tags: sudo, solaris, su, logs

I'm currently (cold) reviewing the sulog of a Solaris box and one of my colleagues asserts that if I see a line that ends in `user1-root`, therefore user1 has access to the root password.

I suspect that this could actually be the result of user1 calling `sudo su root` and inputting their own password. I have no live system to test this on, so I'm wondering if someone could confirm my suspicion.

The alternative is that `sudo su root` will result in a log line ending in `root-root`.

Comment: The su in [opensolaris](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=OpenSolaris_b135/cmd/su/su.c) calls [cuserid](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54766/cuserid-3c.html) to get the *from* username, which looks like it'll be the name of the user who first logged in on the tty.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Solaris?  The reason I ask, is that with v11, root is a role by default.  In v11, there is also a feature to allow the user to authenticate to the role with their password to allow for not having a password for the role and/or group account with RBAC ( `roleauth=user` ).  Which means, root might not even have a password to know on Solaris 11.

So the answer depends.

I believe the entry in the sulog would look the same whether they know or don't know the password for the account/role.  If you want to know if they called `su` or `sudo`, you could ask the user, or check the audit logs.  But I'd hope a privileged account was being managed, and that this is an academic type question.

Answer (score 1):

On a Solaris 10 test system, I get `myuserid-root` in the sulog with `sudo su root` instead of `root-root`, as I half-expected. Apparently `su` is capturing SUDO_USER if/when it is set. According to truss, su's environment has both LOGNAME  and USER set to `root` when it goes to write to sulog; SUDO_USER is the only value with myuserid.

Comment: I would hope `su` and/or `sudo` isn't using environment variables as identifying data in log entries. When you run under `truss`, do you see any possible calls to any name services?  Can you run it under `dtrace` and capture all user-space function calls?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I opened up a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52448/room-for-jeff-schaller-and-andrew-henle) to go through the truss & dtrace steps, if you're interested.